# scraping only one side of job page on linkedin? using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, linkedin-api, screen-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import os

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url1="https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3553036109&geoId=118368896&keywords=data%20scientist&location=Tashkent%2C%20Uzbekistan&refresh=true"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Muhammadyusuf/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url1)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'base-search-card__title')
for element in elements:
    titlename.append(element.text)

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

for element in elements:
    try:
        # Click on the job title
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

        # Wait for job description to load
        time.sleep(2)

        page_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")
        for page_element in page_elements:
            print(page_element.text)


        # Scroll down to the next job title
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()

        # Wait for the next job title to load before proceeding
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'base-search-card__title')))

    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
        print(f"Encountered error: {e}")
        # Continue to the next job title if there is an error
        continue
```

Scraping job details from linkedin, the code first takes the titles as elements and for each it clicks then takes all description for that job.

It is clicking and loading the job description page on the right, but for taking details, it is taking only right side, like title, location, the time of posting, not full text. I need details for each job after clicking it. Please help me to solve it. It is taking just this.

for left side and right  side understanding, please see the the image below. righ side is a full description for each job. left side is just the list of jobs.

[here the link page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLCGk.png)